# Disabling laptop's internal keyboard in windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I am using an external keyboard and due to small space I need to place it on top of my laptop build in keyboard. I used to be able to unstall it in device manager for every start up to disable it back in windows 8 but somehow the internal keyboard manage to work even it is "unstalled" and disappeared in windows 10.

I tried to install a wrong driver to the device and it just causes BSOD everytime I boot my laptop.

Is there any way to really disable the internal keyboard of a laptop?

Comment: Still looking for an answer to this. I'd like to *temporarily* disable the internal keyboard in such a way that I can just re-enable it anytime I want

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't disable the keyboard, but it's an alternative to the whole "pick wrong driver to make keyboard stop working".

Some drivers made keyboard still work, others froze my system, today I found out that the Cherry gmbH USB Keyboard stops the keyboard from working and doesn`t mess up my system.

Comment: Vulgar language in conent is unacceptable.

Comment: **Warning** - please do not use obscenities in your posts.Note that other users may have flagged your post as "rude or abusive" leading to possible rep loss or suspension. Please read [Be Nice](http://superuser.com/help/be-nice): "Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive"